# MvxTabBarViewController as first ViewController doesn't appear

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

In my Xamarin.iOS app (which uses MvvmCross), I have registered a custom AppStart that starts either the login screen or the main screen based on whether the user has already logged in. I'm using EntityFrameworkCore to store user data and loading information from the database at startup works fine, the problem comes about after calling `await NavigationService.Navigate<MainViewModel()` from AppStart.

I receive the message in the debugger that MvvmCross navigated (`iOSNavigation`) which is immediately followed by `Request is null - assuming this is a TabBar type situation where ViewDidLoad is called during construction... patching the request now - but watch out for problems with virtual calls during construction`, which as far as I could tell from my research online, is normal. However, the view never appears and the app remains stuck on the launch/splash screen.

My MainViewController (which corresponds to MainViewModel) inherits from MvxTabBarViewController and has the following presentation attribute: `[MvxRootPresentation(AnimationOptions = UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionCrossDissolve | UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, WrapInNavigationController = true)]`.

MainViewController's only constructor is:

```
public MainViewController()
    : base()
{
    // No call to ViewDidLoad here as base() seems to do it for me.
}
```

Everything works fine in my Xamarin.Android project so I'm guessing it's on the iOS side.

MvvmCross 6.3.1.

**EDIT**

The tabs that are to be displayed are created inside MainViewController's ViewDidLoad:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();

    if (ViewModel == null)
        return;

    // There are 3 ViewControllers, all created this way.
    var viewControllerOne = new ViewControllerOne 
    {
        ViewModel = ViewModel.ViewModelOne,
        TabBarItem = new UITabBarItem(ViewModel.ViewModelOne.Title, UIImage.FromBundle("Icon1"), 0)
    };

    ViewControllers = new UIViewController[]
    {
        viewControllerOne,
        viewControllerTwo,
        viewControllerThree
    };
}
```

Each tab inherits from MvxViewController and has the `[MvxTabPresentation]` presentation attribute. The constructor for each of the tabs is:

```
public ViewControllerOne()    // One, Two, Three
    : base("ViewOne", null)    // One, Two, Three
{
    // None of the tab views currently have any bindings to ViewModels,
just a UILabel constrained to the centre of the view for testing purposes.
}
```

I tried running the initial navigation logic on the main thread and no difference was made. This is how I did it inside MvxAppStart.NavigateToFirstViewModel:

```
await Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<IMvxMainThreadAsyncDispatcher>().ExecuteOnMainThreadAsync(() =>
{
    if (isLoggedIn)
        NavigationService.Navigate<MainViewModel>().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    else
        NavigationService.Navigate<LoginViewModel>().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
});
```

Comment: It is a bit hard to help you with the information provided. How are you instantiating the tab views? The Controller will probably be blank until you've created the tabs

Comment: Also if it just hangs on splash, make sure you await that navigation call on the UI thread.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I have updated the post with more information about the tabs. Forcing the navigation call to run on the main thread didn't solve the problem.

Comment: You are calling `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` on the main thread, what do you expect to happen? I can tell you that you are most likely blocking the main thread doing this.

Comment: I tried running the code async instead (i.e. `await NavigationService.Navigate<MainViewModel>()` and got the same result. If `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` blocks the main thread and therefore shouldn't be used, how come the MvvmCross documentation says to use it for custom app starts? [https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/advanced/customizing-appstart#now-create-an-appstartcs-file-and-add-the-following-code]

My AppDelegate is: `var result = base.FinishedLaunching(application, launchOptions); return result` as per the docs. Should I be doing anything different when using MvxTabBarController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that my ViewModel logic was blocking the main thread.

In my `MainViewModel` I have overridden the `Initialize` task to asynchronously load data from an API for the individual tabs to display.

Originally, I was using `IMvxMainThreadAsyncDispatcher` to run things  on the main thread when I should have been using the `MvxViewModel` methods `InvokeOnMainThread` and `InvokeOnMainThreadAsync`. Now that I'm using these the app launches without issue.

Thank you to everyone who tried to help and special thanks to [Cheesebaron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/368379/cheesebaron) for pointing me in the right direction regarding blocking the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

I see a few issues with the way you are setting up your tabs.

First, In your ViewDidLoad, the following line is likely problematic:

```
    if (ViewModel == null)
    return;
```

You shouldn't do this. If the code execution hits that `return;`, the rest of the code in the method will never execute.

See the example code here: https://github.com/pnavk/Xamarin.iOS.MvvmCross.Tabs

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks but removing this didn't resolve the problem. The reason I added it in the first place was to follow the samples: [link](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Samples/blob/master/XPlatformMenus/XPlatformMenusTabs.iOS/Views/TabBarController.cs)